# Reading in binary file and outputting to another binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles

So im trying to read a binary file into an array and then output that array into another file, which should therefor get me 2 identical files.

But they are different files
[image: files compared]

Why would this be?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int buffer[1000000];

    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("file.bin", "rb");  
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, in);
    fclose(in);

    FILE *out;
    out = fopen("out.bin", "wb");  
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, out);
    fclose(out);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have tried

Comment: An unsigned int is generally 32 bits long, not 8 bits.  Is your source file size divisible by 4?

Comment: You're attempting to read 1 element of size `1000000 * sizeof(int)`, which will fail if the file is smaller. And you're always writing the same size regardless of how much you read.

Comment: @interjay yes, I havent done any error checking as im just trying to understand how binary files worked. I created the file using a for loop and writing it, so it should be fine without error checking no?   for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    data[i] = 1000000 + i;

Comment: Obviously not.  Try error checking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the file, you must only write the bytes that have been read.
For this purpose, you should make these modifications:

- make `buffer` an array of `char` or `unsigned char`
- pass the `fread` and `fwrite` 2nd and 3rd arguments in the opposite order: the 2nd argument is the array element size and the 3rd is the number of elements to read / write
- store the return value of `fread` in a variable, this is the number of elements read, and pass that to `fwrite`.
- repeat the process as long as elements can be read.

Here is a modified version with error checking:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buffer[1000000];
    size_t len;
    int res = 0;

    FILE *in = fopen("file.bin", "rb"); 
    if (in == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open file.bin");
        return 1;
    } 
    FILE *out = fopen("out.bin", "wb");  
    if (out == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open out.bin");
        return 1;
    } 
    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), in)) != 0) {
        if (fwrite(buffer, 1, len, out) != len) {
            perror("cannot write out.bin");
            res = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```